# Android testing: Target app vs Test app?

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-testing

Could anyone explain to me the difference between a *target* app `Context` and a *test* app `Context`?

> You can use the InstrumentationRegistry class to access information related to your test run. This class includes the Instrumentation object, target app Context object, test app Context object, and the command line arguments passed into your test.

The following excerpt from the android developers guide (here: https://developer.android.com/tools/testing-support-library/index.html) is what I am trying to understand.

Answer (score 2):

The target app your app. i.e. The app being tested. AKA the "app under test". Use this in your tests if you want to interact with stuff within your app - load app resources, send an Intent, etc.

The test app is a special app which contains the code and resources for your tests, and has special permissions to poke around with stuff in your app that isn't normally exposed to other apps. Use this if you want to load test-only resources.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the difference now between the test app and the target app, but how would the context differ between the two?